# How to shutdown all cxf web services in contextInitialized method?

Tags: cxf, shutdown

I have a dynamic web application which runs on Websphere Application Server 8.5. If I get an exception in contextInitialized method, I want to shutdown all cxf web services so when a request comes, I want my system to give http 404 or connection timeout error.

I don't want to use "system.exit(0)". I have tried "BusFactory.getDefaultBus().shutdown(true)" but didn't work. My cxf version is 2.7.15. Is there any other  solution?